# Web-scraping with Python: How to scroll into a view by pixels?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python and Selenium. I'm looking to scroll inside a view **by pixels** and not elements. The point is to loop until I've scroll until the end of the list. As a training, I've been trying to scroll all the list of people having liked this instagram post: https://www.instagram.com/p/BuT_u-UAKn1/ . I know how to scroll by elements:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id]/div/a")
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elements[-1])
```

But I would like to scroll by pixels. I've tried to do the following:

```
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elements)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,200);")
```

When doing so, this error occurs:

```
JavascriptException: Message: TypeError: arguments[0].scrollIntoView is not a function
```

Anyone knows how to scroll into a view by pixels?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below has worked for me.

```
#first move to the element
self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
#then scroll by x, y values, in this case 10 pixels up
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -10);")
```

When you say scroll by (0,200). The positive number means scroll DOWN. If you want to scroll UP, use the negative -200

Also see the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy

If you are using a browser that does not support scrollToOptions then switch to a better more supported browser.

Another possible solution is to implement a webDriverWait for the specific element to be visible in the HTML DOM

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css")))
self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

Also you an try using ActionChains

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("id") # the element you want to scroll to 
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

After you move to the element, then you can use the scroll code

You can also try adding in an offset. Some webpages will not load new content if you scroll all the way down to the bottom. Some webpages only load new content as you reach the end of the page.

```
document.documentElement.scrollHeight-10
```

A less conventional way would be to execute javascript within your code.
Also try maximizing your window with selenium. Sometimes the size of the window effects the operation of Selenium

```
driver.maximize_window()

findThis = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("CSS SELECTOR HERE")

jsScript = """
        function move_up(element) {
            element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop - 1000;
        }

        function move_down(element) {
            console.log('Position before: ' + element.scrollTop);
            element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + 1000;
            console.log('Position after: ' + element.scrollTop);
        }

        move_up(arguments[0]);
        """
driver.execute_script(jsScript, findThis)
```